# How to query "similar" node relationship patterns in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have User U1, U2, U3....Un nodes. Then there are Questions Q1, Q2, Q3....Qn. 
This is how the relationship is (User)-[:ANSWERED {answer:1}]→(Question)
Now I want to find out who more similarly answered to U1. 
This [example](http://www.neo4j.org/graphgist?8173017) gives an idea of finding similarity in rating a movie, but answering a question is different..your answer match or don't match.

Comment: You really need to specify what else is stored in the question node, and what "similar" means for questions.  You've stated that it's not the same as the movie example of similarity, but I don't really know what you think it is, just what it isn't.   What have you already tried, and why is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
MATCH (u:User {name:{name}})-[a1:ANSWERED]->(q:Question)<-[a2:ANSWERED]-(u2:User)
WHERE a1.answer = a2.answer
RETURN u2, count(*) as cnt
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 10
```